# why is dart's assert method is not working?

Tags: dart

Dart's assert function is not working for me for some reason.

It wasn't firing on my system

```
Dart VM version: 2.7.0 (Fri Dec 6 16:26:51 2019 +0100) on "windows_x64"
```

It isn't working on dartpad aswell.

Please look at this dartpad https://dartpad.dev/5352f91de86a0b3c58fdf6a8fb64a081.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that assert statements are disable in dartpad since July 2019, you can check the GitHub issue here https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/310#issuecomment-514068279

Answer (score 5):

This wasn't specific to dartpad as it wasn't running on my machine as well on dart `2.7.0`.
I was able to run it with the flag `--enable-asserts`

```sh
dart --enable-asserts lib\main.dart
```

Note:

The flag must be passed as `dart --enable-asserts lib\main.dart` but not `dart lib\main.dart --enable-asserts` as the second approach implies this flag is meant for `lib\main.dart` and not dart.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running brief Dart programs often from the command line to test ideas, it's worth adding the following line to your `.bash_profile` (or similar for other shells):

```
alias dart="dart --enable-asserts"
```

Answer (score 0):

assert is not working on dartpad.dev either replit.com. I test it on 13 Oct 2021. So I used IntelliJ IDEA to work with assert and its working fine.